# "Estar en los cierto" vs. "Estar en lo cierto"

Tags: concordancia-gramatical, concordancia-verbal

No entiendo por qué sería "los cierto" en vez de "lo cierto" en la frase "estaban en los cierto." Pero así la ví en una novela y tambien hay muchos ejemplos en linea. No entiendo con qué "los" tiene concordancia.

¿Por qué no se escribe "lo cierto?" ¿O incluso "los ciertos?" ¿Sería esto incorrecto?

Answer (score 3):

La expresión es *estar en lo cierto*. *Los cierto* no es correcto, tiene que ser una errata. El artículo *lo* va seguido siempre de adjetivo en singular, y no tiene plural: *los ciertos* sería plural de *el cierto*, no de *lo cierto*.